# Sorting in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

We have many sorting algorithms like the `mergesort` which has the complexity of *`O(n*log(n))`* in all the worst, best, average cases. 
`Insertion and Quicksort` as well as have their own complexities in respective cases
Is there an algorithm/process in which we can have a time complexity of `O(n)` for the average cases?

 And also what are the complexities of the System defined function of `Cpp` i.e. `sort()` and `sorted` in `Python 3`

Answer (score 0):

Counting sort can give you O(N). But only under the condition that there are just a few distinct values.

Comment: Just to clear the ambiguity of the statement,the range of numbers should be small , countsorts complexity depends on range of the number for example if the difference between lowest and the highest integer is 10^6 then the complexity would be 10^6